# Underline EditText Hint Text

Tags: java, android

Is it Possible to underline the hint text in Androids **EditText**? I want to underline the hint text and disable underline for the real text in my edit text. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a charsequence programitically using [FromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) 
In that add

```
String str =    "Start Text <u>Your Hind</U> End Test";
```

Or simply add a string in **strings.xml**

```
"Start Text <u>Your Hind</U> End Test"
```

and set to EditText

See Sample
Code

### Strings.xml

```
<string name="str_hint">Hello <u>This is hello</u>world!</string>
```

### Layout File

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/str_hint" />
```

## The Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

setHint takes a CharSequence, so you can send it an underlined spannable and it ought to work.